# How to select a specific value from an array of objets or return a specific value in ruby or rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following and need to figure out how to get a reference to the specific object that satisfies the select and is the zeroth element of that array in Ruby or Rails 3.2. What I'd like to do is return the id of that value

```
 price.price_attributes.select {|attr| attr.network_attribute_id == 528 }[0] ? 'would like to return the object.id here - attr.id? or something' :  'nothing here'
```

How would I get a reference that object? I could use another technique if makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try:

```
price.price_attributes.select {|attr| attr.network_attribute_id == 528 }.try(:[], 0).try(:id) || 'nothing here'
```

Comment: sadly, this will fail if the array does not have a matching `attr.network_attribute_id == 528` (undefined method `[]` for nil). A simple `.try(:[], 0) || 'nothing here'` would solve the problem

Comment: sorry, I really need to return the specific id of that object. I apologize as the question could have been clearer

Comment: @timpone you can chain the `try` method: `.try(:[], 0).try(:id) || "no id found"`

Comment: @MrYoshiji - I just added that. Thanks for being my editor-in-place.

Comment: driving home - so will take a look in like half hour or so. sorry

Comment: @MrYoshiji the `try(:[],0)` is not needed at all actually. `select` will naturally return an `Array` so `[0]` is fine even though it may result in `nil`. so I guess, given rails version and implied ruby version, `select{#...}[0].try(:id) || 'nothing here'`. All that being said depending on the architecture it might also be implied that  `price.price_attributes.find_by_network_attribute_id(528).try(:id) || 'nothing here'` is sufficient and would be potentially far more performant.